# Company still hasn't sent my 1099 tax form

Tags: contractors, taxes

I am a translator for a company. I work from home on my computer and they send me emails with documents they need translated when needed. Come March I still had not received any tax form from them. I talked to the lady I am in direct contact with and she told me should would get in contact with the finance department.

Almost a week goes by so I asked for his information to get in contact with him personally. He finally got back to me and told me I am not an employee there, I am a freelance translator for them (which they never discussed with me). He said I will be receiving a 1099 tax form. Mid-March I still haven't received anything. He said they should be receiving the forms soon and they will send them out within a week or so. I emailed him on April 3 asking what was going on since I still have no tax form, and he did not respond.

I am not sure what to do in this situation. Should I keep emailing the finance guy until I get a response, or ask the lady I normal speak with to speak with her boss? I'm getting very worried since it is already April 5. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can file for an extension for any reason (or no reason) but you have to pay what you owe when you file for the extension.  You can file without a 1099 form just by extracting the information you need from your paystubs.  But if you were not aware that you were an independent contractor rather than an employee, I would (strongly) suspect that you're going to get a nasty surprise about the taxes that were not witheld and the self-employment tax that you need to pay.  I would strongly advise talking to an accountant ASAP with whatever information you have to figure out your options.

Comment: You probably need to talk with a tax specialist instead of us. All tax forms for 2015 was supposed to be sent by January 31st of this year.

Comment: Talk to a tax specialist.  There is a thing called a "transcript" that they can request if you authorize.  It will give them (and thus you) a copy of everything filed "on" you for the year.  If they haven't sent it to the IRS, be sure you claim the income.  A missing form that was never given to you is a heck of a lot easier to explain than not declaring a substantial amount of income.

Comment: See also [this question on Money](http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/13931/reporting-income-independent-contractor-received-no-1099/13934#13934)

Answer (score 1):

Confirm on the IRS website, but my experience with filling out the self employment section is even if you do not receive a 1099, you still need to report the income. Just fill out the tax forms and look up what form or line to use if you do not receive a 1099.  Tax software will help you with this.

Also, if you are self employed it is probably worth the money to have a professional prepare your taxes.  They are well versed for these types of problems and can also direct you toward various deductions you may not be aware of or how to file them.

Lastly, this is probably not the right forum to ask this question.  The IRS website has a lot of good documentation though as there are numerous Q&A sites for tax questions.